# jcl-over-slf4j: set logging level howto

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

That's pretty strange but only FATAL & ERROR level works for me, even when I specify a TRACE level.

**LoggingTest.class:**

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SLF4JTest {

    private static Log _LOG = LogFactory.getLog(SLF4JTest.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        _LOG.fatal("Fatal works!"); //works
        _LOG.error("Error works!"); //works
        _LOG.warn("Warn works!"); //doesn't work
        _LOG.info("Info works!"); //doesn't work
        _LOG.debug("Debug works"); //doesn't work
        _LOG.trace("Trace works"); //doesn't work
    }
}
```

**log4j.properties:**

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS}
```

Comment: It's probably because you have slf4j-simple on your classpath somewhere. Are you sure the conversion pattern is applied? If not, it's because of slf4j-simple.

Comment: Looks like you are using commons logging and not slf4j. It's probably using some default level for commons logging and is not respecting your slf4j configs (as it shouldnt...since they are different logging frameworks)

Comment: @ErikPragt maybe, don't know how to check. So can you tell me please how to check that and how to solve?

Comment: @coffeeaddict don't know how to check. So can you tell me please how to check that and how to solve?

Comment: Could you please provide versions of any logging dependency existed in your project?

Comment: @Dmytro I'll do that in few hours.

Comment: @Dmytro how to do that? There are tremendously big pom.xml in parent and sub projects. Can you specify which one do you need?

Comment: Search in the workspace of your IDE using File Search by all pom.xml files such words: "slf4j", "log".

Answer (score 3):

There may be some errors in your project.

- First, if you want to use SLF4J into your code, you must change the type of your instance:

  ```
  // Instance of SLF4J
  private static final org.slf4j.Logger _LOG = 
          org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(SLF4JTest.class);
  ```
- Second you must rename the file `slf4j.properties` to `log4j.properties`.
- Third, you need to add the following libraries:

  - slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
  - slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar
  - log4j-1.2.17.jar

However, if you really want to use Commons Logging, adds one more (replace commons-logging-1.1.3.jar by this):

- jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar

Comment: thanks for answer. I just need to log the Hadoop code, so I think I need `Commons Logging`. I have `log4j.properties` file instead of `slf4j.properties` , that was a typo. Also I have all those libraries you mentioned above. So with that in mind what should I do to make those levels to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **common-logging** library, you should have the **only** dependencies for logging  in your pom.xml shown below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Also take care about location of **log4.properties** file. For tests it should be located in **src/test/resources** folder. For an application execution, it should be stored in **src/main/resources** folder.

Comment: I've got all those dependencies. But only `FATAL` & `ERROR` levels work